# How to make user profile fields like phonenumber, gender, publically hidden in a social media app using django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

in a Social media app how to make phone number field as a private/public field.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    groups = models.ForeignKey(Group,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique=True,)
    phone = PhoneField(null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    phone_visibility = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_phone_no(self):
        if self.phone_visibility:
            return(self.phone)
        else:
            return ('')
```

Comment: Do you want this field not visible on forms and serializers by default?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can write

```
<div>
    {% if request.user.phone_visibility %}
         <p> {{request.user.phone}} </p>
    {% else %}
         <p> phone number is hidden </p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

or by using class methods

```
<div>
   {{request.user.get_phone_no}}
</div>
```